# wso2 send email MIME encoded-word header "from"

Tags: email, encoding, wso2, wso2-esb

I have json messages like this:

```
{
  "subject": "Enchanté"
  "sender_name": "Rémi"
  "sender_email" "foo@bar.com"
}
```

I'm using wso2 5.0.0 to send an email using MailTransportSender with something like this:

```
  <property name="Subject" expression="json-eval($.subject)" scope="transport"/>
  <property name="From" expression="fn:concat(json-eval($.sender_name), ' &lt;', json-eval($.sender_email),'&gt;')" scope="transport"/>
```

The smtp email is

```
From: Rémi <foo@bar.com>
Subject: =?UTF8?Q?Enchant=C3=A9?=
```

Note that wso2 correctly encodes the Subject: but not the FROM: . It should be :

```
From: =?UTF8?Q?R=C3=A9mi?= <foo@bar.com>
```

How to make wso2esb encode the sender_name as well (rfc2047) ?